# Comparing observations

Tags: compare, stata

Suppose my dataset includes the following variables:

```
set obs 100
generate var1 = rnormal()
generate var2 = rnormal()

input double(id var5 var6)
1 1052 17.348
2 1288 17.378
3 1536 17.387
4 2028 17.396
5 1810 17.402
6 2034 17.407
end

input double(id var5 var6)
1 10000 0.4
2 22000 0.55
3 25000 0.5
4 40000 1
end
```

I need to delete rows of ids that have **an increased value of var5 and reduced value of var6 compared with at least one other id**. In the first example, number 4 with 2028 and 17.396 should be deleted. In the second example, number 3 with 25000 and 0.5 should be deleted. After the elimination, the observations of the three variables should look like this:

```
1 1052 17.348
2 1288 17.378
3 1536 17.387
5 1810 17.402
6 2034 17.407

1 10000 0.4
2 22000 0.55
4 40000 1
```

while `var1` and `var2` should remain intact.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you clarify your criteria? In the example, the dropped observation has is the smallest value of  var5 and is the only obs with a negative var6. What is the comparison to other observations (ids) you are trying to make? Consider expanding your example with a couple of other ids you would want to drop.

Comment: `an increased value of var5 and reduced value of var6 compared with at least one other id` its not clear to me what that even means

Comment: Sounds like `drop if var5 > min(var1, var2) & var6 < max(var1, var2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very odd because you appear to say that you have a dataset with completely unrelated variables. You have an initial dataset of 100 observations with variables `var1` and `var2` and then a secondary dataset with 6 observations with variables `var5` and `var6`. Your objective appears to be to remove observations, but only for values contained in variables `var5` and `var6`. This looks like spreadsheet thinking as Stata only has a single dataset in memory at any given time.

The task of identifying observations to drop requires that you compare each observations with values for `var5` and `var6` with all other observations with values for those variables. This can be done in Stata by forming all pairwise combinations using the `cross` command.

Here's a solution that starts with data organized exactly as you presented it and separates the two datasets in order to perform the task of dropping the observations based on `var5` and `var6` values. Since the datasets appear completely unrelated, an unmatched `merge` is used to recombine the data.

```
clear
set obs 100
generate var1 = rnormal()
generate var2 = rnormal()

input double(id var5 var6)
1 1052 17.348
2 1288 17.378
3 1536 17.387
4 2028 17.396
5 1810 17.402
6 2034 17.407
end
tempfile main
save "`main'"

* extract secondary dataset 
keep id var5 var6
keep if !mi(id)
tempfile data2
save "`data2'"

* form all pairwise combinations
rename * =_0
cross using "`data2'"

* identify cases where there's an increase in var5 and decrease in var6
gen todrop = var5_0 > var5  & var6_0 < var6

* drop id if there's at least one case, reduce to original obs and vars
bysort id_0 (todrop): keep if !todrop[_N]
keep if id == id_0
keep id var5 var6
list

* now merge back with original data, use unmatched merge since 
* secondary data is unrelated
sort id
tempfile newdata2
save "`newdata2'"
use "`main'", clear
drop id var5 var6
merge 1:1 _n using "`newdata2'", nogen
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this without separating the datasets. The task of identifying the observations to drop require a double-loop to make all pairwise comparisons. There is however no command in Stata to drop observations for just a few variables. In the following example, I switch to Mata to load the observations to preserve and then clear out values and save the observations back into the Stata variables:

```
clear
set obs 100
generate var1 = rnormal()
generate var2 = rnormal()

input double(id var5 var6)
1 1052 17.348
2 1288 17.378
3 1536 17.387
4 2028 17.396
5 1810 17.402
6 2034 17.407
end

* an observation index
gen obsid = _n if !mi(id)

* identify observations to drop
gen todrop = 0 if !mi(id)
sum obsid, meanonly
local n = r(N)
quietly forvalues i = 1/`n' {
  forvalues j = 1/`n' {
    replace id = . if var5[`i'] > var5[`j'] & var6[`i'] < var6[`j'] & _n == `i'
  }
}

* take a trip to Mata to load the data to keep and store it back from there
mata:
// load data, ignore observations with missing values
X = st_data(., ("id","var5","var6"), 0)

// set all obs to missing
st_store(., ("id","var5","var6") ,J(st_nobs(),3,.))

// store non-missing values back into the variables
st_store((1,rows(X)), ("id","var5","var6") ,X)
end

drop obsid todrop
```

Alternatively, you can manually move up values by doing some observation index gymnastics:

```
clear
set obs 100
generate var1 = rnormal()
generate var2 = rnormal()

input double(id var5 var6)
1 1052 17.348
2 1288 17.378
3 1536 17.387
4 2028 17.396
5 1810 17.402
6 2034 17.407
end

* an observation index
gen obsid = _n if !mi(id)

* identify observations to drop
gen todrop = 0 if !mi(id)
sum obsid, meanonly
local n = r(N)
quietly forvalues i = 1/`n' {
  forvalues j = 1/`n' {
    replace id = . if var5[`i'] > var5[`j'] & var6[`i'] < var6[`j'] & _n == `i'
  }
}

* move observations up
local j 0
quietly forvalues i = 1/`n' {

    if !mi(id[`i']) {
        local ++j
        replace id = id[`i'] in `j'
        replace var5 = var5[`i'] in `j'
        replace var6 = var6[`i'] in `j'
    }
}

local ++j
replace id = . in `j'/l
replace var5 = . in `j'/l
replace var6 = . in `j'/l

drop obsid todrop
```

Comment: It's a range, from observation j to the last observation. See `help in`.